# Red supergiants with luminosities significantly above the Humphreys-Davidson limit?

Tags: red-supergiant, eddington-luminosity

The M33 red supergiants (RSDs) LGGS J013312.26+310053.3 and LGGS    J013339.28+303118.8 both have luminosities significantly above the [Humphreys-Davidson (HD) limit](https://www.aanda.org/articles/aa/full_html/2020/03/aa37374-19/aa37374-19.html) (logL 5.76 and 5.68 [[source](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0004-637X/750/2/97)], current research puts the RSG luminosity limit at around 5.5). Even the most luminous cool supergiants like Stephenson 2 DFK 49 and HD 269551 A have much lower luminosities (logL is around 5.59 for both [[source](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/1538-3881/abab15/meta)] [[source](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/1538-4357/aca665)]). So how are those two stars this luminous? They probably aren't foreground stars.

Comment: You should explain the abbreviations you use at least once. RSD and HD are not self-explanatory, and ambiguous, and probably only understood by people who deal with these topics on a daily basis. I did that for you here now. Maybe even the link I used to explain HD already helps as those authors investigate the variation of the HD limit wrt metallicity